# Where can I find advice on building my own Node.js TypeScript framework

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have posted a question about advices on design and architecture and review on a framework I'm creating: [github.com/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts](https://github.com/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts)

Basically: I'm in the right direction and have I done some mistakes in the architecture. This required a bit of reading of the documentation and code can't be posted as such.

All my questions were closed or voted down, telling me to go somewhere else. Very *nice* people gave me a [list of possible Stack Exchange Network sites](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c): none of them seem to fit the topic (although other similar question get answered on Stack Overflow, software engineering stack... which is very frustrating).

Simple question: Where do I post this kind of question now?